Does anyone include *non*spliced reads in a differential splicing analysis?
AFAIK, the various tools for calculating differential splicing all calculate $\Delta\Psi$ (i.e. the change in the Percent Spliced-In). This involves examining the various relative aboundances of splice junctions in a "cluster" or gene and flagging it when a change of this percent (or percent-vector) is large, or has a small enough p-value.
That's all fine, but I feel that it's missing something major: namely the fact that some (overlapping) reads/transcripts might not be spliced at all and this fact will be completely ignored/overlooked by the algorithems.
As a simple example we can observe the "retained intron" problem. (I know that some methods look for differentially retained introns, but my point is that this is a special case of ignoring the unspliced reads...) A cluster with a retained intron only contains one junction (the intron itself). Thus, the PSI is always equal to 1, and so it can never be differentially expressed. If we would add to the cluster a fake "junction", the reads that overlap the 5' splice-site but are not spliced, we would have the differentially retained introns emerge from leafcutter.
In fact, if we added the sum of the reads that overlap the 5' splice-sites from each of the junctions (again, that are not spliced) as a fake "junction" we would have information that we do not otherwise have: how many reads do not participate in this cluster.
So the question is: Would this informative and if so, why do people not do it? it seems like a relatively simple change to make (for leaf-cutter, I'd simply modify regtools to pass over the bam again and collect the unspliced reads over each of the 5' ends)
I'm sure I'm missing something, either a publication/tool that does this, or a good reason why this isn't interesting....
Happy to hear from you!

Good question, belated upvote. Sorry I can't help, albeit I know this area not at the level required to give a solid answer.
